# itms-services://?action=download-manifest Not Work in IIS

Tags: ios, xcode, iis

I have created an ios apps and let selected devices download&install on idevices browser safari.So make a link like this:

```
 <a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://myserver.com/Info.plist">
```

and when i click it was popup a message "cannot connect to myserver.com".

Then i figure out IIS missing MimeType  so i add back to it.

```
 .ipa application/octet-stream
 .plist text/xml
```

But finally when i click on it no response at all,why?
i doubt info.plist setting was wrong or something.

Here are my info.plist setting:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
<key>AppStoreFileSize</key>
<integer>4329818</integer>
<key>ApplicationProperties</key>
<dict>
    <key>ApplicationPath</key>
    <string>http://myserver.com/Apps.ipa</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.app.app</string>
    <key>IconPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>http://myserver.com/icon.png</string>
        <string>http://myserver.com/icon.png</string>
        <string>http://myserver.com/icon@2x.png</string>
        <string>http://myserver.com/icon-72.png</string>
    </array>
    <key>SigningIdentity</key>
    <string>CSR Certificate</string>
</dict>
<key>ArchiveVersion</key>
<integer>2</integer>
<key>CreationDate</key>
<date>2012-10-10T09:02:39Z</date>
<key>Name</key>
<string>AppName</string>
<key>SchemeName</key>
<string>AppName</string>
```

Comment: This is a info.plist of your app not a manifest. Did you create this Plist with Xcode -> Organizer -> Archives -> Distribute -> Save for enterprise or ad-hoc deployment?

Comment: Yea i think i noe what the problem d, suppose " Save for enterprise"
thank yea

Answer (score 3):

You code needs to look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>items</key>
        <array>
                <dict>
                        <key>assets</key>
                        <array>
                                <dict>
                                        <key>kind</key>
                                        <string>software-package</string>
                                        <key>url</key>
                                        <string>http://www.example.com/test.ipa</string>
                                </dict>
                        </array>
                        <key>metadata</key>
                        <dict>
                                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                                <string>com.name.name</string>
                                <key>bundle-version</key>
                                <string>1.0</string>
                                <key>kind</key>
                                <string>software</string>
                                <key>title</key>
                                <string>Name</string>
                        </dict>
                </dict>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Remember to change:

```
Bundle Identifier= <string>com.company.name</string>
Installer Name= <string>Name</string>
Ipa Download= <string>http://www.example.com/test.ipa</string>
```

---

Change the `<string>http://www.example.com/test.ipa</string>` to where ever you located you ipa for install.
Create you Install.plist or Start.plist what ever and go into mobile safari and type: `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://www.example.com/whatever.plist`
And it should go a head and download it there may be some bugs when downloading.
Remember that the ipa needs a valid UDID= unique device identification.

Hope this helped.

Best Regards Silas.

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS8, un-encrypted plist downloads are not accepted anymore.

So you need a valid ssl certificate and change the scheme to https. You can test this with amazon s3 for example.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use Https for all urls in .plist file